# Running script once when X is initialized

Tags: linux, bash, startup, gnome

1. Where should I put a bash script if I want it to be executed once during X startup as part of system bootup. For example, I want to start up VPN on my machine as root user once X starts up.
2. When X initializes (lets say GDM in my case) or when a user logs in using a DM (desktop manager) is it considered a login shell?
3. Also I would like to run programs as long as I am logged in using X. For example, I want to run Dropbox as long as I am logged in using Gnome.

Comment: For your question 1, should be in `/etc/rc5.d`. See [this table](https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts) for the various run levels

Comment: Any attempts to read manuals there?

Answer (score 1):

Anything you want to run when a user logs into an X session, you want to put in the `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` file in the user's `$HOME`.

This page has a pretty good explanation:

http://fluxbox.sourceforge.net/docbook/en/html/app-setup.html

Answer (score 1):

You should put them in `.xinitrc` . This is mine :

```
#!/bin/zsh
#Map Capslock to ESC
setxkbmap -option caps:escape &
#Wallpaper
feh --bg-scale /mnt/data/Dropbox/pic/character/samurai.png
#turn off beep sound
xset -b
#mouse speed
xset m 1/5
#keyboard repeat speed
xset r rate 200 30
#font
xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/local
xset fp rehash
#urxvtd daemon
urxvtd -q -f -o &
#Disable touchpad tapping and scrolling when typing
syndaemon -t -i 2 &
#Hide cursor
unclutter -keystroke &
#Redshift - change your screen temp to reduce eyestrain
redshift &
# Dropbox
dropboxd &
#dwm status
while true
do
  xsetroot -name "nXqd"
    sleep 20s
done &
#Window manager
exec dwm
```